# How to change a string of text with Javascript based on URL search params?

Tags: javascript

I have a URL that I want to link to with a few different URLSearchParams that will update a string of text within the HTML.

My URLs will be like:

```
example.com?code=GreenMonkey
example.com?code=PinkPanda
example.com?code=BlueCat
```

Then I will have some JS in the HTML:

```
const params = new URL('https://example.com?code=GreenMonkey').searchParams;
params.get('code');
```

Then I want to change a string of text within the HTML:

```
<div class="code">Change this text based on the 'code' param.</div>
```

For example:

```
If 'code' param = GreenMonkey > change string to "Hello world"
If 'code' param = PinkPanda > change string to "Goodbye world"
If 'code' param = BlueCat > change string to "Aloha world"
```

I'm stuck on how to achieve the last part. Any direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object that contains the key-value of the code then fetch and replace it using `string literal`.

```js
const params = new URL("https://example.com?code=GreenMonkey").searchParams;
const code = params.get("code");

const codeElement = document.querySelector(".code");

function changeCode(element, code) {
  const codeStringObj = {
    GreenMonkey: "Hello World",
    PinkPanda: "Goodbye world",
    BlueCat: "Aloha world"
  }

  element.textContent = `change ${codeStringObj[code]} text based on the 'code' param`;
}

changeCode(codeElement, code);
```

```html
<div class="code">Change this text based on the 'code' param.</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set up a hashtable object using same keys as in url.

```js
const dict = {
  GreenMonkey: "Hello world",
  PinkPanda: "Goodbye world"
}


const params = new URL('https://example.com?code=GreenMonkey').searchParams,
      key = params.get('code');
  
document.querySelector('.code').textContent = dict[key]
```

```html
<div class="code">Change this text based on the 'code' param.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const params = new URL("https://example.com?code=GreenMonkey").searchParams;
const code = params.get("code");
let new_text = null;

switch(code) {
  case 'GreenMonkey':
    new_text = 'Hello World';
    break;
  case 'PinkPanda':
    new_text = 'Goodbye world';
    break;
  case 'BlueCat':
    new_text = 'Aloha world';
    break;
  default:
    new_text = '';
}

document.querySelector(".code").textContent = new_text;
```

```html
<div class="code">Change this text based on the 'code' param.</div>
```